# How to filter empty/null multidimensional arrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, laravel-5, array-filter

[
    `array:26[
     0 => array:2 [
                0=>"array:2 means array is not empty"
              ]
     1 => array:1 [
                0=>"array:1 means array is empty or null"
              ]
    ]`

array 1 upto 26 are empty arrays which will be filtered using array_filter but the problem was it cannot filter empty arrays.

The goal was this - return !empty($arr), using array_filter. But still the empty arrays are not filtered. I tried using array_values and then apply array_filter but still the result was the same. Any Ideas on how to filter these empty arrays? That would be a greater help for me thank you! by the way this is a multidimensional array. ][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0wB5B.png)

Comment: Ensure your question includes your code, expected result and data. An image to your result is not really useful. Have a look at the Help -> Tour

Answer (score 0):

The position 1 of the array is not empty, it has an element which is an array(0 => '')
try:

```
function notEmpty($a)
{
    if(is_array($a))
        return array_filter($a, "notEmpty");
    return !empty($a);
}
$result = array_filter($yourarray, "notEmpty");
```

ps: `empty(array(0 => ''))` evaluates to false as `empty('')` evaluates to true